# How to store a deleted value in a variable?

Tags: plsql

When i delete a row from my table called "Categorie". I want the deleted naam record in a variable. This way i can change 'Economie'(see code) to the deleted variable. So i can build the string with the deleted category.

example
**if my table countains:**

- Sport    omschrijving
- Economie omschrijving
- Binnenland   omschrijving
- Buitenland   omschrijving

And i delete the row sport i want to store the value sport in the deleted variable.

**result i have now is:**

Mail verstuurd naar Klaas@test.nl met tekst Beste Klaas Vaak , uw abonnement is opgeheven voor Categorie Economie

**result i want is :**

Mail verstuurd naar Klaas@test.nl met tekst Beste Klaas Vaak , uw abonnement is opgeheven voor Categorie **'deleted value'**

How is the best way i could achieve this?

```
 CREATE TABLE Categorie
 (  
  naam           VARCHAR2(64) PRIMARY KEY,
  omschrijving   VARCHAR2(2048)
 );

 CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER Verwijdercategorie 
 before Delete 
 ON Categorie
 DECLARE
 categorieinvoer varchar2(30);


PROCEDURE gebruiker (categorienaam varchar2)    
AS
  voornamtemp varchar2(30);
  achternaamtemp varchar2(30);
  emailadresstemp varchar2(30);
  bodyText varchar2(300);
  categorie varchar(30):= categorienaam;

  CURSOR emp_cursor IS 
  SELECT VOORNAAM, ACHTERNAAM,EMAILADRES from mailabonnee,categorieabonnement,categorie
  where categorie.naam = categorieabonnement.categorienaam
  and categorieabonnement.mailabonneeid = mailabonnee.id
  and categorie.naam = categorie;

BEGIN
      FOR employee_rec IN emp_cursor LOOP 
      voornamtemp:= employee_rec.VOORNAAM;
      achternaamtemp:= employee_rec.ACHTERNAAM;
      emailadresstemp:= employee_rec.EMAILADRES;
      bodyText:= 'Beste ' || voornamtemp || ' ' || achternaamtemp || ' , uw abonnement is 
      opgeheven voor Categorie ' || categorienaam;
      sendMailAbonnee(bodyText,emailadresstemp);  
      end loop;
END gebruiker;

begin
categorieinvoer:= 'Economie'; -- Value that need to be changed;
gebruiker(categorieinvoer);
end Verwijdercategorie;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger's body I think you should replace

```
categorieinvoer := 'Economie';
```

with

```
categorieinvoer := :OLD.NAAM;
```

Give that a try.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: WHen i try your code in sql developer Bob Jarvis i get the following message of binds. What am i doing wrong?

![BINDS][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/waIoG.png

Comment: NVM i already find my fault becaus i was trying to change a tabel whit was in my cursor thats why i get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique to support this is to use a bit flag, such as `Deleted` to indicate that when set `true` indicates that the record has been deleted (or conversely, an `Active` flag that when set `true` indicates that the record is not deleted).  If you use audit fields in conjunction with this, you can track who changed the value of your bit flag.

Of course, this increases the complexity of queries you write that access this table, because they then have to have a filter added : `...WHERE DELETED = FALSE` or `...WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE`.

Another technique is to utilize so-called "History" tables on those tables where you need to maintain deleted values.  These history tables would have the same structure as the regular table, and when a record is deleted from the regular table it would be inserted into that tables history table.